# Build pc from scratch for first time

Tags: build

I just built a pc for the first time and am trying to power it on. Everything was connected properly I checked like 5 times. When I start it up the system and cpu fan spin, harddrive spins when it start up, but there is not display. I am not getting anything on the screen. No bios screen or anything else. I took out the ram memory to see if it starts beeping but it does the same exact thing. Can any one help me? I would appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this @ superuser.com

Comment: A few little things you might want to mention - what's the motherboard, and what is the beeping pattern would be the first things i'd ask

Comment: Did you observe ESD precautions when assembling the computer? In other words, 'did you zap the motherboard while you were installing it?'

Comment: I'd also suggest trying a known good stick of ram and PSU, but then again, i have spares ;p

Answer (score 4):

If there is absolutely no beeping at all and you're absolutely certain that the video card and all the other components are installed correctly (try pulling everything out and reseating each item), I can think of two options.  First is that your motherboard is DOA.  The other is that if the motherboard has built in video, you could try hooking that up instead of the graphics card and see if the screen pulls up there.  Oftentimes, if a motherboard has built in video, the bios default is to output to that plug rather than any installed video card.

Answer (score 2):

Is your screen cable plugged into your motherboard or GPU?

Comment: Plus give us some more specs!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no beeping, are you sure the PC speaker is connected?  My new mobo had a tiny little speaker that looked like a little cylinder on the end of two short wires with a two pin connector at the other end - I didn't even recognize it as a speaker.  My old mobo had the speaker soldered directly on, so I was not expecting a detachable speaker on the new one.

Also, you might want to connect the display to the mobo video port and strip it down to just PSU and CPU and see if you can get into the BIOS setup.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted?  It seems like a perfectly legitimate answer to me.

Comment: Thats why I just upvoted it back to 0 (did not downvote it).